# How can I make the android program display a layout and then wai a few sec. and the display another layout?

Tags: android, layout, timer, wait

Hi guys I just want the program to display the layout main0 and stay for a few secounds then display layout main1 like the programs we see in any phone where an image or layout show up at the start of the program and then fade.

```
/**the main activity */

public class rdwt extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button b1;
Button b2;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main0);
    //Here
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);


}

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==this.b1){
            Intent callwrite = new Intent(this, wto.class);              
            startActivity(callwrite);
        }

        if(v==this.b2){
            Intent callread = new Intent(this, rfr.class);               
            startActivity(callread);
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Thanx jleedev I really appreciate your help 
thanx again

Answer (score 0):

I think there are particularly two different approaches.

1) use a [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and send a delayed message

2) use a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and a [timer task](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to update your layout after a specific amount of time

Code example:

```
TimerTask bla = new YourTask();
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(bla, 1000);
```

And your class YourTask:

```
public class YourTask extends TimerTask {

   public void run() {
     updateYourLayout();
   }

}
```

Edit: However I think you're looking for a splashscreen. This simple tutorial explains how to do it: http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html

Comment: What means not working? Is there an error? And can you show the code?

Comment: I can't figureout what updateYourLayout(); is and how to do it

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TimerTask bla = new YourTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
     
        setContentView(R.layout.s);
        
        timer.schedule(bla,1000);

Comment: package com.rdwt;

import java.util.TimerTask;

public class YourTask extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {
      updateYourLayout();
    }

 }

Comment: and then it asked me to create the methode     updateYourLayout();

Comment: yes thats a method you should implement somewhere in your code and then do there what you want to do.

Comment: How? and what should that method do and how it can update layout

Comment: Ok I read again your question and I think what your really looking for is a splashscreen. This (http://www.anddev.org/simple_splash_screen-t811.html) very simple tutorial shows exactly how to do it. Just follow the steps there.

Comment: Thanx  alot my friend. I really appreciate your efforts to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a technical article about [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Comment: Thanx but still I want more helpfull answer

Answer (score 0):

// Place the following line in your code.

```
   timer(3500); // Waits 3.5 seconds before moving on to the next activity.



   public void timer(int counter){ 
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            // counter is in milliseconds.
            public void run() {             
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(THISCLASSNAME.this,CLASSNAMETOJUMPTO.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
```